# How does the list comprehension work without using the for loop?

Tags: python, list

Below is the one I tried. I am looking for an easiest and efficient alternative way. Any help would be appreciated

```
y = [None] * 620
for i in range(0,204):
    y[i] = 3
for i in range(204,419):
    y[i] = 1
for i in range(419,620):
    y[i] = 2
```

Comment: `[3] * 204 + [1] * (419 - 204) + [2] * (620 - 419)`

Comment: you used this `[None] * 620` for creating list and what stopped you from doing like this `[3] * 204`

Answer (score 2):

How about `y = [3] * 204 + [1] * (419 - 204) + [2] * (620 - 419)`?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can do something like this:

```py
stops = [204, 419, 620]
nums = [3, 1, 2]

array = []
for i in range(total_length):
    if i < stops[0]:
        array.append(nums[0])
    elif i < stops[1]:
        array.append(nums[1])
    # more elifs go here
    else:
        array.append(nums[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```
[ 3 if x >= 0 and x < 204 else 1 if x >= 204 and x < 419 else 2 for x in range(0, 620)]
```

Comment: It's less readability but list comprehension is the fastest and most efficient way to create a list in python